# The Price in the cart should also be updated, as I increase the quantity of products

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm currently working on an Angular 8 Application. I wanted to increase my total amount in the cart with respect to the number of items in the cart. But What's currently happening is that when I increase the quantity the price in the cart remains the same.
Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank You!

Here are the pictures for further assistance.
[image]

[image]

**My HTML Code**

```
<div class="modal-footer padding-10">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" (click)="addToCart(filteredRecipe,'isExtra')"
           class="btn-second btn-submit">Add to Cart
          <span *ngIf="recipeTotal!=0">{{recipeTotal | currency :'GBP':'symbol':'1.2-2'}}</span>
        </a>
      </div>

   <div class="u-line">
      <div class="product-quantity padding-10"><span class="text-light-black fw-700 fs-16">Quantity</span>
        <div class="input-group quantity">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button (click)="quantityControl('-')" class="minus-btn" type="button" name="button">
              <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="text-center" [(ngModel)]="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button (click)="quantityControl('+')" class="plus-btn" type="button" name="button"><i
              class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**My TS Code**

```
  quantityControl(flag) {

    if (flag == '+') {
      this.quantity = this.quantity + 1;
      if (this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice != null) {
        this.recipeTotal = this.recipeTotal + this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice;
      }
    } else {
      if (this.quantity != 1) {
        this.quantity = this.quantity - 1;
        if (this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice != null) {
          this.recipeTotal = this.recipeTotal - this.filteredRecipe.RecipePrice;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: which variable is bound to the total price on html?

Comment: 'recipeTotal' is the variable bound to it.
I've just updated my HTML code you can see

Comment: can you post working minmal code on stackblitz or plunkr so we can sort it out? looks like scope issue to me.

Comment: I've shared the whole code of my 'html' and 'Ts' file here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-47aqjw?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Your stackblitz is not working...

Comment: Maybe it's due to API's and services I'm using in my project. So its difficult to run the project on stackblitz